# Creating new files in groups in new folders are inconsistent

Tags: c#, parallel-processing, consistency, skew

With the help of some users, they were able to provide assistance to read a text file, create new files in a group in a new folder with a specified count.  For instance, my text file that I am reading has 10,000 lines (in this case).  I grouped it to read 1,000 lines and create a new folder each time.  The expected output should be 10 folders created with 2,000 objects in each folder (1 image file, 1 metadata file).  However, the actual output is 10 folders created with either plus or minus 2,000 objects in each folder.  The actual output also does not always put the respective 1 image file with its 1 metadata file together.  Some times they are in the same folder (which it should be), while other times they are in separate folders (which it should not be).

I stepped through the program and do not understand why this happens.  Below is the code that I have used to perform these actions above.

```
private string[] sourceline = new string[] {};
private string folder = string.Empty;
private int bs = 1000;

...

Thread t1 = new Thread(
new ThreadStart(() =>
{
    sourceline = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\guids.txt")

    int batchcount = (sourceline.Length / bs) + 1;

    for (int i = 0; i < batchcount; i++)
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\zz\" + i.ToString());
    }

    Parallel.For(0, sourceline.Length, x =>
    {
        folder = ((int)(Array.IndexOf(sourceline, sourceline[x]) / bs)).ToString();

        //i call a function here to go retrieve my document
        //findmydoc(objsto, sourceline[x]);  <== this is how I call my function
    }

    Array.Clear(sourceline, 0, sourceline.Length);
    sourceline = null;

}));
t1.IsBackground = true;
t1.Start();
```

The program does read through the entire text file and create the correct amount of files that I expect to see (20,000 in this case).  As mentioned, it is not consistent with creating 2,000 objects per folder and does not always put both files in the same folders.  Any insight is greatly appreciated!  Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you folder variable is shared among all tasks and the value of it keep changing.
Try to make a private variable inside the Parallel.For

```
Parallel.For(0, sourceline.Length, x =>
{
    string folder = ((int)(Array.IndexOf(sourceline, sourceline[x]) / bs)).ToString();

    //i call a function here to go retrieve my document
}
```

Comment: I use the "folder" variable in the function that I call (commented area) to give the files that I am creating in the function the location of the folder (if that makes sense).

Comment: When I create the variable "string folder" inside the Parallel.For, I get a "The name folder does not exist in the current context" because I use the 'folder' variable inside the custom function to reference the location.  That's why I declared the "private string folder" at the top.

Comment: you can change the custom functions to accept the folder as a parameter instead of using a shared variable.

Comment: Oh yea...haha.  Thanks for the tip, Aladin!  That certainly did the trick for me.